# Disable downloading source for C# internal methods, like object.ToString()

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-6.0

Is there any way to disable the decompilation of C# internal method like ToString()?
Everytime I accidentally ctrl+click on the methods, and it spends some time to download the library source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change resharper's behavior on `Options` -> `External source` (Tools section on the bottom). Select "Default Visual Studio navigation".